# Location of Kozak Sequences

Tags: genetics, exons

Are Kozak sequences always found within the first exon? I know that the first exon must be right next to the promoter so that RNA polymerase can start transcription, but just wondering how that would work if kozak sequences aren't always found in the first exon.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site. Please also note that one of the requirements for this site is some [prior research by you into what might be the answer to your question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). On that note - what comprises a Kozak sequence (in bases) and how does this answer your question...?